# Module tensorflow not found with poetry installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dependencies, python-poetry

Trying to make a project with poetry, all libraries are working except tensorlfow. Using vscode with venv in project.
code with error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import tensorflow as tf

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\Python\Interview\alfa\baseline-popular-transactions.ipynb Cell 2 line 4
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 from collections import Counter
----> 4 import tensorflow as tf
      6 import warnings
      7 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "alfa"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["fckscl <dimapugach31102003@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10,<3.12"
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem = "0.30"
tensorflow = "^2.11"
numpy = "^1.26.0"
pandas = "^2.1.1"
ipykernel = "^6.25.2"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

python version 3.10.6

added tensorflow and tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem with 'add' command, because tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem version 0.34.0 throw different error.

Comment: Same problem and I found the explanation and a solution on the Github Poetry repository: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8271#issuecomment-1696053565